# PHP upload video files to database

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I am working on a school project that let users upload video files to a server. Server will compress the video using ffmpeg and store the file in upload folder. Other users will be able to stream the uploaded videos.

My question is how do i retrieve the video that ffmpeg generated and store the link in the database?

i am using this code but it only retrieve path of the original video.

```
$filePath = dirname(__FILE__);
```

partial code of Upload.php

```
$target_dir = "upload/"; //where you want to upload the files to
$target_file = $target_dir.basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$fileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$newFileName = $target_dir.sha1(pathinfo(basename($_FILES['file']['name']), PATHINFO_FILENAME)).'-'.time().'.'.$fileType;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $newFileName);
$unique_id = rand(1000000,9999999);

shell_exec("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i ".$newFileName." -vcodec libx264 -crf 20 \"upload\\{$newFileName}\" > logfile.txt 2>&1");

/// save information into database
                $username = "root";
                $password = "";
                $hostname = "localhost"; 
                $dbname = "test_database";

                //connect to the database
                $dbc = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname) or die ("could not connect to the database");

                //execute the SQL query and return records
                 $result = mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO `viewvideo` (`vID`, 'video_id`, `video_link`) VALUES ('', '".$unique_id."', '".$newFileName."')");

                if(!$result){echo mysqli_error($dbc); }

                echo $result;

            /*  
                declare in the order variable
                $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql); //order executes
                if($result){
                    echo("<br>Input data is succeed");
                } else{
                    echo("<br>Input data is fail");
                }
            */  

                //close the connection
                mysqli_close($dbc);
```

output
[image]

Comment: look at the error here ***it's telling you where it starts,*** you have a missing tick `\`` for the `video_id` column.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to move the uploaded file to a directory of your choice. A way to prevent files overwriting each other is creating a new name for it. Do this when the upload is a success.

**Properly uploading & adding the video to the database**

```
$target_dir = "video/"; //where you want to upload the files to
$target_file = $target_dir.basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$fileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$newFileName = $target_dir.sha1(pathinfo(basename($_FILES['file']['name']), PATHINFO_FILENAME)).'-'.time().'.'.$fileType;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $newFileName);
```

After that you'll have to create a table & insert two core things; a unique/token generated ID for the video and the `$newFileName` path.

You can either use a function which generates a token/id which includes alpha-numeric characters or something simple as this
`$unique_id = rand(1000000,9999999);`

Lets consider you have a table `videos` with 3 columns; `vID`, `video_id` & `video_link`

`vID` should be an auto incrementing INT. `video_id` would be a INT and the `video_link` a TEXT type.

After that it's SQL.

```
$result = mysqli_query($db_connection, "INSERT INTO `videos` (`vID`, video_id`, `video_link`) VALUES ('', '".$unique_id."', '".$newFileName."'");
if(!$result){echo mysqli_error($db_connection); }
```

**Retrieving it** would be something like this. Be sure to add this on another page. Let's consider **stream.php** as the page's name for streaming the video.

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = trim($_GET['id']);
    //check if it exists
    $result = mysqli_query($db_connection , "SELECT `video_id`, `video_link` FROM `videos` WHERE `video_id`='".$id."'");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    //does it exist?
    if($count>0){
        //exists, so fetch it in an associative array
        $video_arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        //this way you can use the column names to call out its values. 
        //If you want the link to the video to embed it;
        echo "Video Link: ".$video_arr['video_link'];
    }else{
        //does not exist
    }
}
```

And finally, creating a link to it: `http://your-website.com/stream.php?id=video id here`

Comment: i cant use move_uploaded_file because ffmpeg has already move the video file to the dest location. any other suggestion?

Comment: Upload the file first & move it to the new location **then** use ffmpeg to compress it. Also, added the retrieving portion.

Comment: So it'll be something like this: `shell_exec("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i ".$newFileName." -vcodec libx264 -crf 20"); Fixed.  
          `

Comment: hi. i am getting  error upload\upload/ffbaf58f1231628f9ac2a583f038b51719006ec6-1452589716.mp4: No such file or directory and the data is not added into the database. will be glad if you can help.

Comment: `\"{$newFileName}\"` change it to that. the upload directory is already included in `$newFileName`

Comment: Ah, apologies. Made a little mistake in the syntax. Here's the fixed line for the $result variable. `$result = mysqli_query($db_connection, "INSERT INTO `videos` (`vID`, video_id`, `video_link`) VALUES ('', '".$unique_id."', '".$newFileName."'");`

Comment: i solve the conversion error with ffmpeg but data is still not inserted into data with the same error  Erreur de syntaxe pr�s de ''video_id`, `video_link`) VALUES ('', '8126281', 'upload/ffbaf58f1231628f9ac2a58' � la ligne 1video.mp4 is sucessfully compressed and uploaded

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100533/discussion-between-mick-jack-and-irfan-dahir).